# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\SUN\\Desktop\\oops in python.txt'

Tags: python

I used a online compiler to access a document in my Desktop using python.

```
file = open(r"C:\Users\SUN\Desktop\oops in python.txt")
for i in file:
    print(i)

file.close()
```

While, I run this code, I am getting this error

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\SUN\\Desktop\\oops in python.txt'`

I Checked the file name and the directory. It's all correct. And I continue to get the same error.

Why am I getting this error?

When I run this code in a Offline Compiler, **It works.** And I Got the output as required.

Comment: Online compiler (thankfully) does not have access to your hard drive, offline does. When this code is run somewhere online, the file path refers to the file system of the remote host, not your local one.

Answer (score 4):

It's because the online compiler can't access you system files. The website your are using creates a session for you and runs your code on their servers so you can only access the files you created and saved unto their server during your session.

Answer (score -1):

I think the correct filename is "`loops in python.txt`" and not "`oops in python.txt`".
Aren't you missing the `l` in the beginning?

- On windows, you can also use forward slashes (`/`).
- `with open` ensures the file is closed automatically. i.e.:

---

```
with open("C:/Users/SUN/Desktop/loops in python.txt") as f:
    for l in f:
        ...
```